# How to Deal With Different Scales of Values for Each Coordinate in K-Means Algorithm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, k-means, feature-extraction

I am practicing K-means using python. 
I am working with a set of shopping data, and the input dataset looks something like this.

Input table headers:

- [userID]
- [money_spent_on_clothes] int
- [money_spent_on_food] int
- [money_spent_on_shoes] int
- [money_spent_on_Monday] int
- [money_spent_on_Tuesday] int
- [money_spent_on_Wednesday] int
- [money_spent_on_Thursday] int
- [money_spent_on_Friday] int
- [shopping_hours_am] int
- [shopping_hours_pm] int

I want to use how much they spend in each category, what day they shop the most, and how many hours they spend in shopping during the day into consideration when clustering users.

There are few discrepancies in the dataset.

- units don't match: $ vs. hour
- feature types are mixed. First 3 features are about category, next 5 features are about day of the week, and the last 2 features are how much time they spend during the day (am vs. pm).

I am wondering if K-means clustering can be done on this dataset & features I have stated, and if it can be done, what kind of normalisation must be applied in order for this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally scaling is done on a per column basis, so there is nothing to worry. Or do you have something else in mind. Have you tried the StandardScaler from scikit-learn?

Comment: Thank you. I will try Standardscaler.  I am glad to know that having different types of features like the above is no problem as long as they are scaled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) and due to its properties it is easy to use with with any euclidean driven K-Means algorithm (Use it as a black box).

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it :)